# Programmatic Access to Critical Updates

Tags: api, critical-update

My company has a large number of orgs that we need/want to be able to manage the status of Critical Updates across. Ideally, we'd like to be able to do this using some kind of script or CLI so our DevOps team can automate it. In order to do this, it would be necessary to have some kind of programmatic access to Critical Updates, either as some kind of metadata objects or sObjects.

I also found this "Idea", which implies that at least the asker (and voters) do not know of a way to do this, but maybe there's something they don't know:

https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A0000003SPUQA2

My question, then: Is there any way to programmatically access, via query or any sort of API, the status and/or details of the current Critical Updates in any given org?

Answer (score 0):

You can theoretically set up a [headless browser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headless_browser) and enable them that way, but this is not supported and may break in the future. There is no documented available API for programmatic access at this time. The design rationale is that administrators should manually review these updates to avoid unforeseen problems, and an API would defeat that design goal. For now, you'll want to vote on the idea, and perhaps experiment with Selenium or another web driver to automate your tasks.